# MFC Owner Draw Listbox - GetItemDataPtr returning garbage

Tags: mfc, clistbox

So I've derived my listbox from CListbox, set the resource style up to be just like the demo project I got (HASSTRINGS, OWNERDRAW - VARIABLE, NO SORT).

The listbox populates, draws OK, TRACE statements give me the pointer value for each item being drawn.

Until I scroll.

Before I scroll the item at the bottom of the visible list is traced as (20 is the lpDrawItemStruct->itemID)

```
MyClass::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct) ...
```

20 - 0x036f3d90 {m_Event={ size=658 } m_ListName= ...

The first DrawItem event I handle after the scroll

20 - 0x0127d248 {m_Event={ size=1073736252 } m_ListName= m_ImageName=...} - The evaluation was aborted because an unhandled exception occurred.

Why is the pointer different?

It doesn't need the scroll to reproduce this problem, selection does it too.

Any bright sparks out there can tell me what to look for?

Comment: Sounds like you have a bug in your code. We cannot see your code. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Are you sure you are using `SetItemDataPtr` instead of `SetItemData` before?

Comment: When populating, send an `LB_ADDSTRING` message first to add the caption string. Save the return value, which is the index of the new item. Use that index to send an `LB_SETITEMDATA` message containing the pointer to your item data. When retrieving the item data, send an `LB_GETITEMDATA` message. You can do this from inside of the `DrawItem` function, using `lpDrawItemStruct->itemID`. Works perfectly for me; I have this code as described running in an MFC project right now for an owner-drawn list box. As IInspectable has already said, if you can't make it go, [edit] your code into the question

Comment: Thanks for the comments - it was just a *bug* }-( (index from a different listbox being used). The thing still isn't working quite right - I'll try and work it out for myself before announcing that MFC is broken.